# Fail to compile due to package not found

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

**Problem**: Failed to build using "**Run As > Ant Build**" on `build.xml`

When I try to compile a demo java, it failed to compile. Attached with `build.xml` and corresponding eclipse setting. Required package in place but still failed to compile.

[Here is the demo source code](https://github.com/fxcm/ForexConnectAPI) You can download this financial tools to have fun too. Warning: involve very high risk investment

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="build" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <property name="name" value="Login" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="${basedir}/src" />
    <property name="build" location="${basedir}/build" />
    <property name="build.classes" location="${build}/classes" />

    <target name="checkos">
        <condition property="bin.dir" value="${basedir}/../../../../bin">
          <os family="windows" />
        </condition>                      
        <condition property="bin.dir" value="${basedir}/../../../../lib">
          <os family="unix" />
        </condition>    
    </target>

    <!-- App build -->
    <target name="build" depends="checkos" description="Builds the ${name} application">
        <!-- Creating directory -->
        <mkdir dir="${build.classes}" />

        <!-- Compiling sources -->
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
               destdir="${build.classes}"
               includeAntRuntime="false"
               debug="${build.debug}"
               deprecation="true"
               verbose="false"
               optimize="true"
               classpath="${bin.dir}/java/fxcore2.jar" >
        </javac>

        <!-- Creating JAR-file -->
        <jar jarfile="${build}/${name}.jar">
            <fileset dir="${build.classes}" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="login.Main" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="fxcore2.jar" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="rebuild" depends="clean, build" description="Rebuilds project" />

    <!-- Clean -->
    <target name="clean" description="Removes all temporary files">
        <!-- Deleting files -->
        <delete dir="${build}" />
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="checkos" description="Rebuilds and run ${name}">
        <copy file="${bin.dir}/java/fxcore2.jar" tofile="${build}/fxcore2.jar" overwrite="true" />
        <java jar="${build}/${name}.jar" fork="true" failonerror='true' dir="${bin.dir}">
            <jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=${java.library.path}${path.separator}${bin.dir}${path.separator}${bin.dir}/java" />
            <arg line="--login {LOGIN}" />
            <arg line="--password {PASSWORD}" />
            <arg line="--url http://www.fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp" />
            <arg line="--connection Demo" />
            <arg line="--sessionid {SESSIONID}" />
            <arg line="--pin {PIN}" />
        </java>
    </target>

</project>
```

Error output as follow:

```html
Buildfile: C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\build.xml
checkos:
build:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:3: error: package fxcm.fxcore2 does not exist
    [javac] import fxcm.fxcore2.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private static void printAccounts(O2GSession session) throws Exception {
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GSession
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:6: error: package com.fxcore2 does not exist
    [javac] import com.fxcore2.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class SessionStatusListener implements IO2GSessionStatus {
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol: class IO2GSessionStatus
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private O2GSession mSession;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GSession
    [javac]   location: class SessionStatusListener
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public SessionStatusListener(O2GSession session, String sSessionID, String sPin) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GSession
    [javac]   location: class SessionStatusListener
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onSessionStatusChanged(O2GSessionStatusCode status) {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GSessionStatusCode
    [javac]   location: class SessionStatusListener
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         O2GSession session = null;
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GSession
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             session = O2GTransport.createSession();
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable O2GTransport
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         O2GResponseReaderFactory readerFactory = session.getResponseReaderFactory();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GResponseReaderFactory
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         O2GLoginRules loginRules = session.getLoginRules();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GLoginRules
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         O2GResponse response = loginRules.getTableRefreshResponse(O2GTableType.ACCOUNTS);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GResponse
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         O2GResponse response = loginRules.getTableRefreshResponse(O2GTableType.ACCOUNTS);
    [javac]                                                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable O2GTableType
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         O2GAccountsTableResponseReader accountsResponseReader = readerFactory.createAccountsTableReader(response);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GAccountsTableResponseReader
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\Main.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             O2GAccountRow accountRow = accountsResponseReader.getRow(i);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class O2GAccountRow
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         case TRADING_SESSION_REQUESTED:
    [javac]              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TRADING_SESSION_REQUESTED
    [javac]   location: class SessionStatusListener
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         case CONNECTED:
    [javac]              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable CONNECTED
    [javac]   location: class SessionStatusListener
    [javac] C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\src\SessionStatusListener.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         case DISCONNECTED:
    [javac]              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable DISCONNECTED
    [javac]   location: class SessionStatusListener
    [javac] 18 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\clint\Documents\programming\Projects\fxcm\java_sample\NonTableManagerSamples\Login\build.xml:31: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you copy-paste the text from the build errors in the Console view (or maybe the Problems view)?

Comment: Posted build errors

Comment: Where is the online location of the build file? Did you write it or did it come from some project?

Comment: nothing changed. you can find source code above. I've posted the link

Comment: download link http://www.fxcodebase.com/wiki/index.php/Download you can find source code under `C:\Program Files\Candleworks\ForexConnectAPIx64\samples\java\NonTableManagerSamples\Login` after installation

Comment: Have you tried building it from the command line? For instance, running `ant rebuild` at `C:\Program Files\CandleWorks\ForexConnectAPI\samples\java\NonTableManagerSamples\Login>` or equivalent?

Comment: build with `ant build` in cmd successful, is it possible to build with eclipse?

Comment: Successful build, now failed to run `Login.jar` showing this msg `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fxcore2/IO2GSessionStatus
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)...`

Comment: That is interesting. I used to use Eclipse in the past, but I use IntelliJ more these days for various reasons. Many others have switched to IntelliJ as well. See for instance https://www.slant.co/topics/607/~best-java-ides-or-editors , where IntelliJ is at 94 score and Eclipse is at 59 score. That said, IntelliJ comes from JetBrains, and they may have an aggressive marketing team and the like that affects public opinion. But still. I do not personally wish to go back to Eclipse.

Comment: Can you run it from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for recomemdation. Testing out IntelliJ now

Comment: Tried with in cmd `java -jar Login.jar` same error output. Thought Eclipse is the tradition common choice and picking it right away. Have been using JB collection for other languages, Eclipse is no match

Comment: What about `ant run`?

Comment: `ant run` in cmd did the job. Thanks mate. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command line, the following commands might work:

```
ant rebuild
ant run
```

from the path `C:\Program Files\CandleWorks\ForexConnectAPI\samples\java\NonTableManagerSamples\Login>` or equivalent.

As a side-note, IntelliJ may be a good alternative to Eclipse, I prefer IntelliJ myself personally.